# How Do I Host A Protected React/Next.js Page on A Seperate Server for Maximum Protection?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, express, next.js, jwt

I am making a React/Next.js app that has a page which requires a login to see. Every React/Next.js app I've seen has a folder `pages` which contains all of the pages. I usually protect the views that require a login with a middleware or an express backend running Passport.js and a local authentication strategy. But how would I make it so that the page that's protected is actually hosted on a separate url?

I know you might be thinking that this is pointless because if the main server controls authentication, couldn't whoever controls that server set any user to authenticated and access the protected data anyway?

In this case, that attack vector is not relevant because I'm using something called "Lit Protocol" which creates the login JWT on a decentralized network of dedicated servers so spoofing authentication isn't really a problem.

So just to reiterate the original question, how would I make it so that the page that's protected is actually hosted on a separate url? And I can take it from there.

Comment: Have you considered using an iframe that handles not only the authentication, but all the protected routes? That way you handle the cookie in that separate domain and stay authenticated.

Comment: That sounds like a great idea, do you know of any resources that explain this or any code bases that have an example of this?

Comment: Not this exact case, but often iframes are used to handle payment forms so it can be embedded in the websites for PCI compliance. For example: let's say I want to use Paypal to handle payments, so I in my website https://example.com/ I use the Paypal npm library which will create an iframe pointing to Paypal website, so all the data never travels through my website.

Comment: Additional information: https://www.verygoodsecurity.com/blog/posts/iframes-as-a-security-feature
https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/what-is-iframe/

Comment: This is great info thanks! Checking out the links now